# are branching journeys possible in gatling

Tags: gatling

Is it possible for a Gatling journey to contain branches or to stop at certain steps with a given probability? I've had a bit of a look and it looks like journeys are static but I can't see anything obvious to say that these things aren't possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is possible with Gatling's doIf, doIfEquals, doIfOrElse etc. See https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/general/scenario/ for details.